# How to send celery all logs to a custom handler . in my case python-logstash handler

Tags: python, logging, logstash, django-celery, celery-task

In my Celery application I am getting 2 types of logs on the console i.e celery application logs and task level logs (inside task I am using logger.INFO(str) syntax for logging)

I wanted to send both of them to a custom handler (in my case python-logstash handler )

For django logs I was successfull, by setting handler and logger in settings.py but I am helpless with celery

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
def initialize_logstash(logger=None,loglevel=logging.DEBUG, **kwargs):
    # logger = logging.getLogger('celery')
    handler = logstash.TCPLogstashHandler('localhost', 5959,tags=['worker'])
    handler.setLevel(loglevel)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    # logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    return logger

from celery.signals import after_setup_task_logger
after_setup_task_logger.connect(initialize_logstash)
from celery.signals import after_setup_logger
after_setup_logger.connect(initialize_logstash)
```

using both after_setup_task_logger and after_setup_logger signals solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Celery provides a [after_setup_logger](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#after-setup-logger) signal that is triggered after Celery has set up the logger. Among other few arguments, the signal passes the logger object which you can add your custom logging handlers to.

```py
from celery import signals

import logstash
import logging


@signals.after_setup_logger.connect
def setup_logstash_logger(logger, *args, **kwargs):
    handler = logstash.TCPLogstashHandler('localhost', 5959)

    # More logger/handler configuration
    # handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    # ...

    logger.addHandler(handler)
```

After fine-tuning Celery's logger you can simply rely on it to send the app messages to Logstash, even if you need to send your own messages:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info('My message')  # This message will also be sent to Logstash
```